# ops hub migrating TFS 2010 to visualstudio.com Cyclic error

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am using the OpsHub migration tool and have the following error

"OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. Pend Rename failed after {41} attempts. Cannot resolve the Cyclic Rename/Move encountered"

At first i wondered if the error was due to a project not being included in the migration but this doesn't seem to be true as I get the error when trying to migrate all the projects I have.

I am not sure how i can start to debug this. I cannot even see what project has the problem.

Have tried just running a retry but does same issue occurs.

Comment: Can you please send us log files from C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs directory. Send us all files in zipped format to ovsmu@opshub.com. We will analyze logs and comeback to you on same thread for resolution of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update for anyone encountering the same issue using the Utility.
This was a special case during Cyclic Rename/Move resolution algorithm that OpsHub Utility supports and implements.

It has been fixed in v1.1.0.001. Hence, newer versions of the utility wont have this issue.

@Buzzby : You can use the newer version to solve your problem.

Thanks.